# Looking for research related to burising sensitivity and rate of heeling

Tags: red-blood-cell, healing

Are there studies/data on the potential correlation between how quickly a body heals itself and how prone to bruising the body is?

I've been reading that oxygen is needed in the healing:

> Wounds need oxygen to heal properly. Exposing a wound to 100% oxygen may speed healing. Hyperbaric oxygen therapy can be done in a number of ways. It can be given in a special type of room called a hyperbaric oxygen chamber. [-Hyperbaric Oxygen Therapy for Wound Healing](https://www.hopkinsmedicine.org/health/treatment-tests-and-therapies/hyperbaric-oxygen-therapy-for-wound-healing#:%7E:text=Wounds%20need%20oxygen%20to%20heal,called%20a%20hyperbaric%20oxygen%20chamber.)

And that bruising essentially is the pooling of blood from damaged blood vessels.

> Bruises occur when blood vessels break, due to some kind of force, and leak blood into areas under the skin. [-Mount Sinai: Bruise Information](https://www.mountsinai.org/health-library/injury/bruise#:%7E:text=Bruises%20occur%20when%20blood%20vessels,be%20very%20tender%20to%20touch.)

This has led me to hypothesize "On average a person with a higher sensitivity to bruising will heal faster than a person with low sensitivity.". This hypothesis was created out of the idea that due to the increased concentration of oxygen found at the wound location (caused by the trapped/pooling of red blood cells), the damaged cells will be able to utilize this increase to heal quicker.

I'd like to do some research to determine if this hypothesis is true, plausible, unlikely, false or unknown.

If the hypothesis is true then some blood vessels might be more prone to leak blood when damaged. This trait would have been selected for, because it would help the initial healing process by increasing the oxygen concentration at the wound location.

This is just my hypothesis and I'm looking for information to guide my research.

Comment: Why do you think that the blood at a bruise site has more O2 than elsewhere in the tissue? Read up on responses to bruising by the body...

Comment: I do not believe that the blood at the site has more O2 than blood anywhere else in the body. I believe that a higher concentration of blood forming in a location normally without blood will increase the density of O2 in the area.

Comment: If you think about the biological processes that go on - why does a bruise appear? Why does it not disappear in a short time-frame (as it should if blood flow happens...) What happens to the O2 in the blood cells? What happens if the blood flow is stopped (tied in to q 1 and 2 above) - where does the O2 go and is it replenished? BTW use the format @ followed by username to notify someone you've made a response to a comment e.g. @Tolure will notify you of a comment.

Comment: @bob1 the red blood cells get trapped after the body heals the damaged blood vessel. The red bloods cells give the bruise its redish colour. After the red blood cells break down the oxygen is released to the area and the bruise changes colour. Now I will accept that there might not be a mechanism to allow for a damaged cell to take advantage of this. If so please draft an answer stating as such.

Comment: No this is homework for you - I think your understanding of the timing of events is off. Blood gets trapped almost immediately. The body uses up the O2 (normal cellular respiration) and changes colour (that's not due to respiration, rather degradation of the RBCs) - so why would there be more O2 at the bruise than elsewhere?

Comment: @bob1 would you agree that a volume of oxygen-rich hemoglobin has a higher concentration of O2 than the same volume of tissue? If so why would the concentration of O2 in an area not change when the ratio of tissue to hemoglobin changes due to the pooling of blood caused by bruising?

Comment: @Tolure You need constant circulation of blood for it to stay oxygenated. Blood just sitting there isn't resupplied with new oxygen.

Comment: Agreed but I'm only looking at the initial state. Where the hemoglobin still had oxygen. Once the hemoglobin have released their oxygen then yes I agree the hemoglobin wouldn't help in the healing. Now when the trapped hemoglobin release their oxygen that they already had prior to being trapped could it help the healing?

Comment: @Tolure How fast do you think the O2 from the pooled blood will be gone? How fast do you think healing processes are?

Comment: @bob1 O2 Used up: Very quick and Healing: very slow. 
I also know that sometimes just a little benefit now can have compounded benefits later on.